# Drupal - open node body in new window

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

So i got a problem and really haven't found any solution to this so i hope someone here can help me.

I got site with book navigation module. My front page has multiple blocks in it with each block containing book navigation and listing contents of different book.

The problem is that I need to open book pages from one block in a new window and this new window should only contain node's body data without template stuff surrounding it.

I've managed to open these node's in new window with custom module listing only book pages from given book but i can't figure out how to print only node body without template stuff in this new window.

My solution for opening book pages in new window is target="_blank" so it might not be the "drupal way" to do this so any tips for this would be appreciated, too.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

in **template.php** (in your theme folder)

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {   
  if (isset($_GET['popup']) && $_GET['popup'] == '1') {
    $vars['template_file'] = 'popup';
  } 
}
```

and create a **popup.tpl.php** inside your theme along with page.tpl.php ,with content

```
<?php echo $content ?>
```

**refresh theme** . now you can add ?popup=1 to any link you wanted . you will get only $content

for example '**user/1?popup=1**' :)

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to apply to Drupal 7.  Any thoughts on how you'd adapt this answer for Drupal 7?  I'm currently attempting to use `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__popup';` in place of your 'template_file' line.  And it *does* execute the template, but the $content is undefined, so only the Title shows, with no content.

Comment: @cmcnulty in drupal 7 , `echo $content` is `echo render($page['content'])`

Comment: A major leap forward!  It still prints the sidebars, but at least now it's showing the content!

Comment: @cmcnulty include only content , remove all other variables

Comment: @cmcnulty also refer [ajaxify drupal](https://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api) . I've built a module on same concept

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is body text without any of the other "stuff", I recommend overriding the default theme for the content type you're using. You can either do it by hand (writing the PHP), or the Content Template (Contemplate) module might work.

Comment: But this behavior should happen only for users who aren't logged in.

So basically i need to be able to specify custom template for contents of the popup window. It shouldn't affect rest of the same content types. Only the ones opened in a new window.